# ObjectContext.AddObject vs ObjectSet`1.AddObject methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

On one of our projects we are using DbFirst EntityFramework.

And all entities are being added to database by [ObjectContext.AddObject(string, object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx) method.

I want to change these calls with [ObjectSet<TEntity>.AddObject(TEntity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method calls. So I will have strongly typed version of the method.

Before

```
var person = new Person();
e.AddObject("Persons", person);
```

After

```
var person = new Person();
e.Persons.AddObject(person);
```

Are there any possible issues with such replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no issues with this replacement. I'd even contend that there is an issue with the former, viz. the string parameter which has no compile-time check (and that's probably exactly the reason why you want to change this).

The current EF source shows that under the hood the `ObjectSet.AddObject` does nothing but executing `ObjectContext.AddObject(string, object)`. The string argument is safely supplied by EF itself.

The EF 4 source is not publicly available, but I have no reason to assume that things are fundamentally different there.